# Change navigation styles depending on the current path Gatsbyjs

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, styling

I am pretty new to Gatsby Js, I am quite struggling to understand how I can change my Header component styling based the current path. The Header component is common to all the pages but the styling should change slightly when I navigate to other pages like /portfolio and /team. Due to Gatsby SSR in production on the first page load when the path is "/portfolio or "team" the proper styling for the header doesn't change since the code to modify the className of the header component happens in the browser. Is there any way using the Browser API or SSR API to add/remove the correct className of the Header component? I hope I made it clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually its easy. Gatsby comes with a handy plugin called [react-helmet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-helmet) make sure you have it inside your `package.json` if you don't, check the [Docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet/) for installation.

All you need to do is to import `helmet` inside your targeted **page** for example `portfolio.js`

```js
import { Helmet } from 'react-helmet'
```

After your `<SEO>` component, add `Helmet` component and define a CSS class within `bodyAttributes` element like so:

```html
<Helmet bodyAttributes={{ class: 'portfolio-page' }} />
```

This will add `portfolio-page` class to the page `body` tag, and so, you can target that class like you would with regular CSS classes.

```css
.portfolio-page .your-navigation {
   background-color: black;
}
```

Here is a [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-heisenberg-6mkxl) for live example. Check `page-2.js` and `components > layout.css`